# Syntax Error - ] at end of return line

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
def filter_list(l):
##newList = []
##for x in l:
##    if isinstance(x, int):
##        newList.append(x)
##return newList

return [x in l if isinstance(x, int)]
                                    ^
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I didn't see any other syntax error posts that helped. The commented code works, and the uncommented code gives me a syntax error on the last ]. I believe the list comprehension is correct, but I'm not necessarily here to ask that. Why am I getting a syntax error on the ]?

Comment: A thumb rule in python,because python doesn't have a compiler  it run the code on the fly. The fact you see a syntax error in a certain place only mean that the program expected something else. There is also a good chance the problem started before(like here when the problem was in the "in")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension syntax is incorrect. Perhaps, you meant to use (assuming `l` is an iterable):

```
[x for x in l if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
out = []
for x in l:
    if isinstance(x, int):
        out.append(x)
```

Comment: This fixed it. Apparently I had misunderstood list comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

An easy mistake to make, but stay at it! List Comprehensions are really useful ways to help shorten code. The last line should read:

```
return [x for x in l if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the explicit loop it's actually easy to convert it to a comprehension.

So if you have:

```
newList = []
for x in l:
    if isinstance(x, int):
        newList.append(x)
```

Then just remove the `newlist = []` and put everything inside a `[...]`:

```
[
for x in l:
    if isinstance(x, int):
        newList.append(x)
]
```

The next step is to move the actual element that is being appended at the front and remove the `:`

```
[
x
for x in l
    if isinstance(x, int)
]
```

That would already work, but generally you also remove the newlines:

```
[x for x in l if isinstance(x, int)]
```

At least that's how I started "learning" comprehensions, maybe it's also helpful for you.

---

The reason why you're code throws the SyntaxError is because it looks like a "ternary" expression that is missing the `else` clause. The ternary looks like this:

```
expression1 if condition else expression2
```

In your case the expression1 is `x in l`, the condition is `if isinstance(x, int)` and you're missing the `else expression2`. And this "ternary" in your case would be wrapped in a list (resulting in a length-one list - if you intended that). For example:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [1 in l if isinstance(1, int) else None]
[True]
```

Comment: The top explanation of how to do list comprehensions is beyond helpful. I had always struggled with them, but that makes it so much easier. The bottom explanation is really helpful as well. Thanks!